# Two dimenional array is not IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, .net, collections

i have function, which has to accept two types of data - Observable collection of MyClass and two dimensional array of myclass. Structure doesnt matter, because i use linq query on these collection. Like - give me all items in collection where Myclass.Value == 3.

So i created function, which accepts parameter of type `IEnumerable<MyClass>`, since both two dimensional array and observable collections implement IEnumerable and it should work.

However, when i try to pass parameter of type MyClass[,] to my function, compile time error occurs  - Argument type Myclass[,] is not assignable to parameter type `IEnumerable<MyClass>`.

What is wrong? thank you.

Comment: I believe your question is inaccurate - you claim that your method accepts a parameter of type `IEnumerable`, but given the error message, I suspect it accepts a parameter of type `IEnumerable<MyClass>`. Those are different things.

Comment: @rich.okelly: How can `Array` implement `IEnumerable<T>` when it's not generic? (See my answer...)

Comment: @rich.okelly: I'd report a docs bug then. Don't believe everything you read on MSDN without thinking it through first :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rectangular arrays *do* implement `IEnumerable`, but they *don't* implement `IEnumerable<T>` (for any `T`, including the obvious element type). You can fix this easily with a call to `Cast`:

```
SomeMethod(array.Cast<MyClass>());
```

Comment: Thank you. I know this might be dumb question, but what exactly is difference between Ienumerable and Ienumerable<MyClass>?

Comment: @VojtechRuzicka: They're different interfaces, although `IEnumerable<T>` extends `IEnumerable`. `IEnumerable<T>` is generic, `IEnumerable` isn't. If you're not already aware of generics, now would be a good time to read up on them :)

Comment: Interesting, I did not know that it was possible to enumerate a two-dimensional array.